# What Is Event In Yii? How To Use Event In Yii?

Tags: php, yii

What is event in yii? How to use event in yii?
Example:

```
public function onForestRan($event){
    $this->raiseEvent('onForestRan', $event);
}
$myComponent->onForestRan = array(new SomeOtherClass, 'eventHandler1');
```

When the event is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

On the page you got this from there is a link to another resource that explains it quite nice
http://www.kofrimpong.com/post/11/How+do+you+create+your+own+event+object%3F

In short you have to raise the event.